# Meteor will not run without Sudo?

Tags: bash, meteor, permissions, terminal, sudo

On OSX Yosemite and the latest version of meteor (1.0.1), no matter how many times I uninstall and reinstall it, I can't seem to get it running without sudo. My user account is an administrator account. But meteor refuses to run without sudo. The errors I'm getting are all:

```
-bash: meteor: command not found
```

I've seen a few posts on here with similar problems. I've tried repairing disk permissions with disk utility. I've tried:

```
sudo chown -R $myUsername /usr/local/bin/meteor
```

I'm not sure what else I can do, because it seems to be a permissions issue. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Additional info that might help:

```
$ sudo which meteor
/usr/local/bin/meteor
$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/bin/meteor
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root wheel 3528 Dec 18 23:14 /usr/local/bin/meteor
$ ls -ld /usr/local/bin
drwx------ 6 502 wheel 204 Dec 18 23:14 /usr/local/bin
```

By the way, `ls -l /usr/local/bin/meteor` only works with `sudo`.

Comment: chmod 777 meteor and add it to enviromental variables

Comment: @BallPython every time you do `chmod 777`, somewhere in the world a kitten dies

Comment: @janos - haha , true) but i suggested it just to make sure it will work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After we clarified the permissions of the `meteor` executable and its base directory,
the problem became quite clear:

- The Meteor binary is located in `/usr/local/bin/meteor`
- Your user didn't have permission to the directory `/usr/local/bin`

The steps to resolve:

1. Add permission on the base directory: `sudo chmod +rx /usr/local/bin`
2. If necessary, add the base directory to `PATH`: `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`

For future reference:

- When you get this kind of error: `-bash: XYZ: command not found`

  - The first thing to check is find the absolute path of `XYZ`, for example `/path/to/XYZ`
  - Try to run with the absolute path `/path/to/XYZ`
- If running with `/path/to/XYZ` gives `-bash: /path/to/XYZ: Permission denied` that means you have a problem with permissions on the file and/or directories:

  - You need read and exec permission on the file itself: `sudo chmod +rx /path/to/XYZ`
  - You need exec permission on all path elements leading up to the file: `sudo chmod +x /path /path/to`
- After fixing permission issues, running with `/path/to/XYZ` should work
- After fixing permission issues, if running with `XYZ` (without full path) still doesn't work, that means `/path/to` is not on your `PATH`. Fix with `PATH=$PATH:/path/to`

*Note: the above `sudo chmod` commands give permissions (read and exec) to all users: owner + group + other. In the case of the OP (and in most common cases), this is perfectly fine.
In situations with more sophisticated permission setup, you might need to be more specific, and use `g+rx` instead of `+rx`.*

**(for the record)**

If it works with `sudo`, and without `sudo` you get `command not found`, that means that `meteor` is on the `PATH` for `root` but not for your user. To make it work for your user, you need to find the path to `meteor` and add it to your user's `PATH`. For example:

1. Become root with `sudo su -`
2. Find the path of `meteor`, run command: `which meteor`
3. Logout from root (Control-D) to return to your user
4. Add the base directory to `PATH`, for example if earlier `which meteor` gave you `/usr/local/bin/meteor`, then do this: `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`

After this, it should work with your user. To make it "permanent", add the last step in your `~/.bashrc`.

If this still doesn't work, then perhaps your user doesn't have the execute permission on the file. Fix that with this command:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/meteor
```

From your comments it also seems your user doesn't have permission on the `/usr/local/bin` directory itself. Fix that with this command:

```
sudo chmod +rx /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't need an admin account to run it, standard user account works fine. You can locate the meteor file by typing `which meteor`. It will tell you what file is being used to execute.

Try removing the `.meteor` folder in your home directory, something like `rm -rf ~/.meteor` and the script from the bin folder `rm /usr/local/bin/meteor` or `rm 'which meteor'` *(speech marks there are the ones above ~)*

And then reinstall meteor **without** sudo using the `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh` command.

Should hopefully install with all the correct permissions...

Comment: I've never installed it with sudo. That's the only part I'm able to do. I just installed it again, and I can't even remove the folder using `rm /usr/local/bin/meteor`, it's telling me "Permission denied"... `which meteor` points me to that directory though. I need to use sudo even to remove it.

Comment: then use sudo to remove the files first

Comment: Yes, I've done that, and reinstalled it. Same thing every time I try to run meteor, create an app etc., it says `-bash: meteor: command not found` unless I run it with sudo.