# Meteor is stuck at downloading meteor-tool@1.3.2_4

Tags: meteor

I have been using meteor framework for the past few days. Now, when i create a new project it downloads meteor-tool@1.3.2_4. But it does not complete download. It seems to be stuck at downloading and shows only following line:

```
Downloading meteor-tool@1.3.2_4...
```

How can i troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Could be related  to the [new CDN](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/6944).

Comment: ss-admin, this is your first time using Meteor!
Installing a Meteor distribution in your home directory.
######################################################################## 100.0%
 
   Downloading meteor-tool@1.1.10...         [                        ] 2% 23900.9s

Comment: I have same things on an old version of 1.1.10 project. Attached above comment.  So the CDN things could be happened on old version? I cannot find how to solve this on that post.

Comment: @jwjin It's a CDN issue and they are trying to solve it. You can view issue [in this link](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6960)

Answer (score 16):

I got it to download by adding `54.192.225.217 warehouse.meteor.com` to /etc/hosts

There's a GitHub issue about it [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6960).

Comment: @MayankAwasthi, can you explain me how or where you added 54.192.225.217 warehouse.meteor.com?

Answer (score 3):

As I haven't found this answer elsewhere with this search and can save some time:

In windows 7, this happened to me because I forgot to run meteor -create in a console with **administrator rights**.

Just **Run As Administrator** and check again.

Hope it helps

Comment: This solved my problem with it hanging on 'create'.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a permissions issue.  As workaround, try running the create command with super user permissions:

```
sudo meteor create myAppName
```

Probably you will need special permissions for running the app too:

```
/MyAppName> sudo meteor
```

If you want to stop running meteor commands with super user permissions, check this: [Meteor will not run without Sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558740/meteor-will-not-run-without-sudo)

Comment: What? Won't that make the entire project owned by root? Sounds like a terrible idea to me; the answers in your [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558740/meteor-will-not-run-without-sudo) are much better. It's just a matter of the `meteor` executable itself being accessible and in the `PATH`.

Comment: `Sudo` doesn't change ownership, `chown` does it

Comment: Of course. But if you create the app as root, it will be owned by root from the start.

Comment: This isn't a bad practice, and will probably cause havoc.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it myself on Mac OS while i run 'meteor update'.
Then i run "ping warehouse.meteor.com" on shell.

And I found that **meteor's network service is not good**, just try it at other times.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade meteor, there is no problem now:

```
meteor update
```

If not, create a new project and test it